Extracting and Joining Variable-Length Account Numbers from Unstructured Strings using Snowflake
Problem:
I have two tables in Snowflake: a dimension table with account information and a fact table where the account numbers are embedded as part of a string in a PARAM_VALUE column of type string. These strings can have various formats and delimiters, or no separators at all, which makes it challenging to extract account numbers for joining.
I want to extract and flatten the account numbers from the PARAM_VALUE column in the fact table, and then join them with the dimension table to display corresponding account details. However, I don’t want to rely on any specific separator or formatting in PARAM_VALUE.
The dimension table contains account details:
Dimension Table (account_dim)



Acc_no




8G4F2H1J9K


4R6T8E3A1L


9W5E2C7R4T


1Q8N6F4G3H


6M9R5E2C1A


3K9P7R4G6T


5E1C8R6T2H


2T4R8G6F1N


7H3G5E2C9R


1L6T8R4E3A


9R5E2C7K3G


4F1N6H8R2T


8G6T4R3E1C


2H5E1C9R7K


6T4R3G6F1N


1C8R6T2H4G


3R5E2C9K7H


5T4R6G1F2E


9K3G5E2C1R


7R4G6T2H1L


Apex Industries


Nova Tech Solutions


Global Finance Corp


Eastern Logistics


Western Digital Inc


Cybernetic Systems


Green Earth Energy


Atlantic Healthcare


Pacific Software


Northern Lights Media


Southern Comfort Foods


Mountain View Ventures


Valley Forge Investments


Oceanic Exploration


Sunset Properties


Cityview Financial


Riverside Manufacturing


Skyline Advertising


Brookside Realty


Lakeside Construction



The fact table has billions of rows and looks like this:
Fact Table (fact_table)



SQL_ID
OBJ_NAME
Param_Value




sql_id890890830492hjkhfdjkd899058390245
customer_table     ('TN190423','TN80989073') ,8G4F2H1J9K &niveiui



sql_id234567890123456789012345678901
orders_table   788686786767%9W5E2C7R4T
jhjhjgjhg


sql_id987654321098765432109876543210
products_table      ('5T4R6G1F2E','4R6T8E3A1L') AC9879879



sql_id456789012345678901234567890123
shipping_table      (' Apex Industries



sql_id111111111111111111111111111111
inventory_table     ' 3K9P7R4G6T,4F1N6H8R2T'  TN0008989



sql_id222222222222222222222222222222
shipping_table      ('9W5E2C7R4T','1Q8N6F4G3H')  Eastern Logistics, Riverside Manufacturing
jkjkhkj


sql_id333333333333333333333333333333
returns_table   '6M9R5E2C1A,3K9P7R4G6T' ' 4R6T8E3A1L,'



sql_id444444444444444444444444444444
customers_table     ('5E1C8R6T2H','2T4R8G6F1N') [ 6M9R5E2C1A , 2H5E1C9R7K ]



sql_id555555555555555555555555555555
orders_table    '7H3G5E2C9R,1L6T8R4E3A'



sql_id666666666666666666666666666666
products_table      ('3K9P7R4G6T','7897')



sql_id777777777777777777777777777777
inventory_table     '9R5E2C7K3G,4F1N6H8R2T' &&&8G6T4R3E1C AC8098908,AC465465



sql_id678901234567890123456789012345
customers_table     Cityview Financial;; Oceanic Exploration



sql_id789012345678901234567890123456
orders_table    TN00098F1NBrookside Realty'



sql_id890123456789012345678901234567
products_table      ('6uyiyiuuitug',' 6T4R3G6F1N ') Apex Industries




Expected Output:
I need to extract patterns from PARAM_VALUE column in the fact_table having loolup at dim table account_dim  and flatten them across fact table rowsand  producing a new table like this:



SQL_ID
OBJ_NAME
searched pattern




sql_id890890830492hjkhfdjkd899058390245
customer_table
8G4F2H1J9K


sql_id234567890123456789012345678901
orders_table
9W5E2C7R4T


sql_id987654321098765432109876543210
products_table
5T4R6G1F2E


sql_id987654321098765432109876543210
products_table
4R6T8E3A1L


sql_id456789012345678901234567890123
shipping_table
Apex Industries


sql_id456789012345678901234567890123
shipping_table
9K3G5E2C1R


sql_id111111111111111111111111111111
inventory_table
4F1N6H8R2T


sql_id111111111111111111111111111111
inventory_table
3K9P7R4G6T


sql_id222222222222222222222222222222
shipping_table
9W5E2C7R4T


sql_id222222222222222222222222222222
shipping_table
1Q8N6F4G3H


sql_id222222222222222222222222222222
shipping_table
Eastern Logistics


sql_id222222222222222222222222222222
shipping_table
Riverside Manufacturing


sql_id333333333333333333333333333333
returns_table
6M9R5E2C1A


sql_id333333333333333333333333333333
returns_table
3K9P7R4G6T


sql_id333333333333333333333333333333
returns_table
4R6T8E3A1L


sql_id444444444444444444444444444444
customers_table
5E1C8R6T2H


sql_id444444444444444444444444444444
customers_table
2T4R8G6F1N


sql_id444444444444444444444444444444
customers_table
6M9R5E2C1A


sql_id444444444444444444444444444444
customers_table
2H5E1C9R7K


sql_id555555555555555555555555555555
orders_table
7H3G5E2C9R


sql_id555555555555555555555555555555
orders_table
1L6T8R4E3A


sql_id666666666666666666666666666666
products_table
3K9P7R4G6T


sql_id777777777777777777777777777777
inventory_table
9R5E2C7K3G


sql_id777777777777777777777777777777
inventory_table
4F1N6H8R2T


sql_id777777777777777777777777777777
inventory_table
8G6T4R3E1C


sql_id678901234567890123456789012345
customers_table
Cityview Financial


sql_id678901234567890123456789012345
customers_table
Oceanic Exploration


sql_id789012345678901234567890123456
orders_table
Brookside Realty


sql_id890123456789012345678901234567
products_table
Apex Industries


sql_id890123456789012345678901234567
products_table
6T4R3G6F1N



Account can be of varying length and can have both account number and account name and can adapt any format. So there should not be split done as it can be seperated or not seperated and can use any seperator in between. SO focus is on searach from dim table.
I tried using the following REGEXP_LIKE query to match and extract the account numbers. However, this query does not return any results. The irregular formatting of the param_value column seems to be causing issues, and REGEXP_LIKE is not finding matches reliably.
WITH flattened AS (
  SELECT 
    f.sql_id,
    f.obj_name,
    a.Acc_No,
    a.Acc_name
  FROM 
    fact_table f
  JOIN 
    account_dim a ON REGEXP_LIKE(UPPER(f.param_value), UPPER(a.Acc_No))
)
SELECT 
  sql_id,
  obj_name,
  Acc_No,
  Acc_name
FROM 
  flattened;


REGEXP_LIKE as per the docs adds explict start/end anchor tokens, so you need to add .* to the front and end of yout string. Also don't use UPPER but instead tell it to do case insensitive matches, thus: REGEXP_LIKE('.*'||f.param_value||'.*', a.Acc_No,'i')

Thanks Simeon. I was tied in some situation so sorry for the delay. This dint worked for me but contains function did worked but that is doing cartesian product and doing that on billions of records makes is totally uselss for our use case. Is there any out of box solution you could suggest to do these operations

Well it rather clear the way you are tackling the problem, is not going to perform well. But at the same time, your question was "why does this fail for me" to which the answer is, REGEXP_LIKE does not work like you have assumed. As to "how should you improve this" you would want to clean-up your data, and allocate a NUMBER key, and then do a normal join on that.
